# How to create xsd file from java classes for web service using Java Maven

Tags: java, xsd

Hello I can't create a xsd file from my Java class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(namespace = "http://www.example.org/employee")
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private String role;
    private Address address;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }


    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

And my POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Employeesample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>SmartHome-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Sample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schemagen</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schemagen</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <transformSchemas>
                        <transformSchema>
                            <uri>http://www.example.org/employee</uri>
                            <toPrefix>empns</toPrefix>
                            <toFile>employee.xsd</toFile>
                        </transformSchema>

                    </transformSchemas>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com/journaldev/bean/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In target folder generated folder "generate-source" but without any xsd file, I think this is something with my pom file, because annotation looks fine 
Can you tell me what is wrong?